# Move a directory recursively using python script

Tags: python, directory

Currently this script creates a folder where the name is the date of the day it was used + the name i want to give, and moves all files modified in the last 12 hours from the selected path to this created folder and then sends it to an Amazon S3. The problem is, i need this script to move not only the files inside the folder, but the whole folder together, how can i do this?

```
import datetime
import sys
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now()
newDirName = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-name")
print ("Making directory" + newDirName)
os.mkdir(newDirName)



import os,time
import datetime
import shutil

import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(hours=12)
strftime = "%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"
created = '/path/of/files'
dest = now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-name")


for root, dirs,files in os.walk(created):
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if mtime > ago:
            print("True:  ", fname, " em ", mtime.strftime("%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"))
            shutil.move(path, dest)

import os

sync_command = f"aws s3 sync {dest} s3://bucket.name/"
os.system(sync_command)
print ("files uploaded")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move directory with its subdirecories recursively, you can use `shutil`:

```
import shutil
import os

source = "/parent/subdir"
destination = "/parent/"
files_list = os.listdir(source)
for files in files_list:
    shutil.move(files, destination)
```